# facebook-ish like iframe in ajax

Tags: ajax, facebook, iframe, frameworks

Can anyone here expand on how I can create a frame within a page, like facebook has (when you click on a user's profile and your not friends with him, for example) in AJAX, or even better - does anyone know a framework that would do the AJAX dirty work, with me writing in PHP?

Something like

```
$frame = new iframeObject;
$frame->setType('a');
```

and so forth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your refering to the Modal dialog boxes then check this out...
http://www.84bytes.com/2008/06/02/jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/